# Change customer attribute required value issue

Tags: magento-1, customer-attribute

On my previous upgrade the required value for my customer attribute was set to `false`. This was set in this file `upgrade-1.0.0-1.10.php`. Now i need to set it to be `true`. So I created my file: `upgrade-1.1.0-1.1.1.php`and put this code:

```
$installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('customer', 'medical_location', 'required', true);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Then I went to my config xml and I changed the value from 1.1.0 -> 1.1.1. I checked in the core_resource and it was updated to my current version. But the required value for my customer attribute is still false. Did I do smth wrong ?

Thx

Comment: Your last version is mentioned as 1.10 is it 1.10 or 1.1.0?

Comment: actually i fixed it , It was my fault . Instead of `required` I put `is_required`.

Comment: please put your comment as answer

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the `required` to `is_required`. Thx